# How to change button icon's color, only if this button is situated on TitleBar?

Tags: extjs

I have a dark-blue toolbar, and I need that buttons situated on TitleBar have `$button-color: #fff;`
and some another color in all other cases, like on the attached image.

[image: TitleBar]

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: create a fiddle and share it

Comment: I suggest to use cls config for that particular case and override that class.

Comment: I suggest to use cls config for that particular case and override that class.

Answer (score 0):

As the buttons located in the title toolbar are a particular case, you should create a [separate ui](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-ui) for this kind of button using [theme mixins](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/core_concepts/classic_theming.html#core_concepts-_-classic_theming_-_using_theme_mixins). You extend the [default mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#css_mixin-extjs-button-small-ui), give it a new name, set the desired parameters

```
@include extjs-button-small-ui(
    $ui: 'titlebarbutton',
    $color: #fff
);
@include extjs-button-medium-ui(
    $ui: 'titlebarbutton',
    $color: #fff
);
@include extjs-button-large-ui(
    $ui: 'titlebarbutton',
    $color: #fff
);
```

And then use it in your button configuration like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    ui: 'titlebarbutton',
    ...
}
```

**OR**

As @D.V. suggested in the comments, you can simply use a css rule:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    cls: 'app-titlebar-button',
    ...
}
```

Note that the button is composed of multiple elements, and this class will be applied to the top one, but the color of the text is determined by the inner element with the class of `x-btn-inner`, so you css rule will look like this:

```
.app-titlebar-button .x-btn-inner {
    color: #fff;
}
```